# Disable action associated with extension 'fileinto' in the managesieve interpreter (Dovecot)

Tags: email, dovecot, sieve

After doing some research on `sieve` support with `dovecot`, I decided to implement it on a virtual machine for testing. I have everything working as expected, i.e. a script is uploaded onto the server, and the interpreter works correctly.

However, I'm having trouble understanding how I could disable an *action*, rather than an entire *extension*. For example, I need to disable the `redirect` *action* to prevent anyone creating a forward. This action so happens to be a part of the `fileinto` extension, which contains other actions that I would like to keep enabled. (Such as `keep`, and `discard`). After reading the RFC standards, I don't think this would be possible.

Out of curiosity, I've tried including the following line to see if I could disable it:

```
sieve_extensions = -redirect
```

However, as expected:

```
managesieve: Warning: sieve: ignored unknown extension 'redirect' while configuring available extensions
```

Because this is an action, not an extension.

Has anyone else run into this situation?

What are some approaches to solve this problem?